# Bad Day of the Month error in simple crontab

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I have a script that should run every 4 hours.
*/240 **** ./autorun.sh

It's my first attempt at creating a crontab and it seemed easy enough, obviously somethings wrong but I don't see why and the error message doesn't make sense to me.   Any help is appreciated.

This is the output after saving my first crontab:

crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.YYOJBl/crontab":23: bad day-of-month
errors in crontab file, can't install.

Comment: does [this Q&A from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855429/crontab-error-tmp-crontab-caljpk5-bad-day-of-month#56855698) answer your question?

Comment: */240 **** ./autorun.sh please format this. I do not see spaces between the****.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/) for creating and testing cron tab times.

Every 4 hours means using the HOURS column and dividing by 4 with the MINUTES set to a fixed amount. So that would be [0 */4 * * *](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/4_*_*_*).

`*/240 * * * *` would mean every 240th minute of an hour. That seems invalid to me as minutes end at 60 so 0-59 are valid numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to Linux and before winging something I try googling first.  In this instance I used information I found on the following website for guidance:           https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/      This is the example I followed: */10 * * * * /scripts/monitor.sh
*/10: means to run every 10 minutes. Same as if you want to execute on every 5 minutes use */5.